# How to change the size of parent div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have on div with a table inside it. The width of div is `100%`. I want to increase the size of my div as soon the table becomes grater than `400px`.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `min-width` on the div instead?

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Without a clear code example, this question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, my take on it is below.

You could try selecting the table, then traverse the DOM tree to select `.parentElement` and change the width using `.style`

EX:

```
...
var x = document.getElementById('tableID');
x.parentElement.style.width = '200%';
...
```